# Why does this pickle reach maximum recursion depth without recursion?

Tags: python, pickle

This is my code, it contains no recursion, but it hits maximum recursion depth on first pickle...

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import pickle

# open page and return soup list
def get_page_startups(page_url):
  html = urlopen(page_url).read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
  return soup.find_all("div","startup item")

#
# Get certain text from startup soup
#
def get_name(startup):
  return startup.find("a", "profile").string
def get_website(startup):
  return startup.find("a", "visit")["href"]
def get_status(startup):
  return startup.find("p","status").strong.string[8:]
def get_twitter(startup):
  return startup.find("a", "comment").string
def get_high_concept_pitch(startup):
  return startup.find("div","headline").find_all("em")[1].string
def get_elevator_pitch(startup):
  startup_soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://startupli.st" + startup.find("a","profile")["href"]).read(),"lxml")
  return startup_soup.find("p", "desc").string.rstrip().lstrip()
def get_tags(startup):
  return startup.find("p","tags").string
def get_blog(startup):
  try:
    return startup.find("a","visit blog")["href"]
  except TypeError:
    return None
def get_facebook(startup):
  try:
    return startup.find("a","visit facebook")["href"]
  except TypeError:
    return None
def get_angellist(startup):
  try:
    return startup.find("a","visit angellist")["href"]
  except TypeError:
    return None
def get_linkedin(startup):
  try:
    return startup.find("a","visit linkedin")["href"]
  except TypeError:
    return None
def get_crunchbase(startup):
  try:
    return startup.find("a","visit crunchbase")["href"]
  except TypeError:
    return None


# site to scrape
BASE_URL = "http://startupli.st/startups/latest/"

# scrape all pages
for page_no in xrange(1,142):
  startups = get_page_startups(BASE_URL + str(page_no))

  # search soup and pickle data
  for i, startup in enumerate(startups):
    s = {}
    s['name'] = get_name(startup)
    s['website'] = get_website(startup)
    s['status'] = get_status(startup)
    s['high_concept_pitch'] = get_high_concept_pitch(startup)
    s['elevator_pitch'] = get_elevator_pitch(startup)
    s['tags'] = get_tags(startup)
    s['twitter'] = get_twitter(startup)
    s['facebook'] = get_facebook(startup)
    s['blog'] = get_blog(startup)
    s['angellist'] = get_angellist(startup)
    s['linkedin'] = get_linkedin(startup)
    s['crunchbase'] = get_crunchbase(startup)

    f = open(str(i)+".pkl", "wb")
    pickle.dump(s,f)
    f.close()

  print "Done " + str(page_no)
```

This is the content of `0.pkl` after the exception is raised:

http://pastebin.com/DVS1GKzz Thousand lines long!

There's some HTML from the BASE_URL in the pickle... but I didn't pickle any html strings...

Comment: Why are you using pickle?  If you are just generating a dictinoary of strings, your output will be more readable and more portable to other languages if you use something like JSON.

Comment: hmmm true enough, didn't occur to me!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's due to circular references inside `bs4.element.NavigableString`, which pickle infinitely tries to chase to get a basic python type.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

BeautifulSoup `.string` attributes aren't actually strings:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div>Foo</div>')
>>> soup.find('div').string
    u'Foo'
>>> type(soup.find('div').string)
    bs4.element.NavigableString
```

Try using `str(soup.find('div').string)` instead and see if it helps. Also, I don't think Pickle is really the best format here. JSON is much easier in this case.

Comment: Ended up using `.encode("utf8")` since there were some non-ascii characters too

Answer (score 4):

Most likely pickle is doing recursion internally, and the file you are trying parse is to big. You could try to increase the limit of the number of recursions allowed.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

This is however not recommended for any type of production ready application, as it may mask actual issue, but could help highlight issue(s) during debugging.

Comment: After setting `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)` I get a different exception: `TypeError: can't pickle HTMLParser objects`  Why is this happening?  I am only pickling returns from the functions that create HTMLParser objects

Answer (score 2):

Pickle cannot handle BeautifulSoup nodes. Similar questions with some workarounds:

- [RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded with Python 3.2 pickle.dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556350/runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-with-python-3-2-pickle-dump)
- [pickle.dump meet RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626003/pickle-dump-meet-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-in-cmp)